# Android UnknownHostException Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, http, ip, android-networking

Here is the situation. My app runs fine, and is able to establish connections with URLs. BUT after a few hours of leaving the app running, all of a sudden the Facebook requests are giving me the following error.

```
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: xyz.com:80
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1037)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1051)
09-26 10:01:25.175: W/System.err(252):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
```

This error happens both on the app and the emulator. When I logout of my app and reconnect to Facebook the connections work again.

I should note: **When I establish connections with my own server, no problem occurs.**

This error is caused by lines such as the following...

```
mAsyncFacebookRunner.request("fql", paramaters,
                new FQLRequestListener());
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? This happens to me, but in my case it's not Facebook but my own server, and I'm using `DefaultHttpClient`.

Comment: may be your internet connection is slow..

Comment: @IlyaKogan, without some code snippet and exception stack trace, there is no much we can help other than guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8957557/741249?

Comment: @yorkw, my code is very similar to the code that THelper linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8957557/326370 . I'm using the same objects as Rob, but with HttpGet instead of HttpPost.

Comment: @IlyaKogan this was never solved cleanly, but I made a workaround that involves making another call when this error occurs, and that fixed the problem. Note, this is a pretty sketchy way of solving this problem.

Comment: @JamesFazio, what's the workaround?

Comment: @IlyaKogan I catch the specific error and then I make the same exact FQL which returns the correct information the second time.

Answer (score 4):

`java.net.UnknownHostException` generally means the IP address of a host could not be resolved, although the actual cause may vary case-by-case. If the code is implemented properly (regardless of which API you use, HttpUrlConnection or DefaultHttpClient) and it is still happened intermittently, it is very likely a bug in old Android system related to DNS caching and TTL management:

[Issue 7904: Android does not support TTL and caches DNS result for 10 minutes](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7904)

This is fixed since Android 4.1, see the extra notes in [InetAddress API Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html):

> **DNS caching**
>
> In Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and earlier, DNS caching was performed both by InetAddress and by the C library, which meant that DNS TTLs could not be honored correctly. In later releases, caching is done solely by the C library and DNS TTLs are honored.

For old Android version, Android suggests adjust Java level DNS properties `networkaddress.cache.ttl` and `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl`, see JavaDoc in [old source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/net/InetAddress.java):

```
/**
 * ... ...
 *
 * <h4>DNS caching</h4>
 * <p>On Android, addresses are cached for 600 seconds (10 minutes) by default. Failed lookups are
 * cached for 10 seconds. The underlying C library or OS may cache for longer, but you can control
 * the Java-level caching with the usual {@code "networkaddress.cache.ttl"} and
 * {@code "networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl"} system properties. These are parsed as integer
 * numbers of seconds, where the special value 0 means "don't cache" and -1 means "cache forever".
 *
 * ... ...
 */
```

Related discussion:

- [UnknownHostException in java (that too only sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906745/unknownhostexception-in-java-that-too-only-sometimes)
- [what is the purpose of Java level DNS caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488587/what-is-the-purpose-of-java-level-dns-caching)

Try adjusting those two properties and see if that makes any difference, if you are targeting on an old Android version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any core conceptual knowledge about network connectivity and DNS caching and TTL management.

but the same problem occurred to me and at that time *Just As a Workaround* I have made *few changes* in the **Facebook project's [Util.java](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Util.java)** [The source project of the Facebook SDK] and then used it for my project. That two changes is just used from different stackoverflow answers.

In the function **openUrl(String url, String method, Bundle params)**

Replace this line,

```
 HttpURLConnection conn =
            (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
```

with these lines,

```
        try {
            InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(url);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
```

And my problem was reduced.

Answer (score 2):

It will help if you can post the code.....but, from my experience, calling httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); resolved this issue.

Comment: Log.wtf(TAG,"Problem Still Exist");